# coldfusion cfchart horizontal bar graph

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

In coldfusion Horizontal bar graph, cfchartseries using cf query resultset & valueColumn contains values as (25,65,20), itemcolumn as empty string, I don't want to display the descriptions. Please refer the attached `Horizontal_cfchart.png`, In x-axis It shows the range from 0 to 70, and we can recognize the horizontal bar data points(25,65,20), but recently the x-axis values displays the range from 0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4........1.0,

I don't know what the exact issue, please share your thoughts.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Leigh, please find the added code

Comment: Thanks, but even ignoring the "smart quotes", that is not a complete, *self-contained* example that demonstrates the issue you described. (In particular the actual data values, since chart axes are generated dynamically). If you are not sure what that is, please see [sscce.org](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry, I will post complete executable code, please confirm one point, Is the range(0,10, 20,30.....70) on X-axis are generating depends on the data entry points(25,65,20)  of horizontal graphs(Y-axis)  as in the attached 'Horizontal_cfchart.png'.

Comment: I can find mistake in code :- In chartArgumentValues structure of Cfchart there is an array(yAxisConfig) for attribute qData.yAxis = yAxisConfig, in this array max-value property is set to 1. This leads to restrict the range upto 1. Thanks for the help Leigh.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and thanks for following up. If you think this could be helpful to others, please post a brief explanation, and maybe a snippet of the relevant code, as an "answer".  Answering your own question is allowed on Stack Overflow.